# How to poll() and remove item from ArrayBlockingQueue without memory allocation

Tags: java, garbage-collection, blockingqueue

I am trying to poll an ArrayBlockingQueue to get the item:

```
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
                closeAppender();
                break;
            }

            if (!TASK_BUFFER.isEmpty() && !TASK_ADDRESS.isEmpty() && !TASK_MARKER.isEmpty()){
                buffer = TASK_BUFFER.poll();
                remoteAdd = TASK_ADDRESS.poll();
                marker = TASK_MARKER.poll();

//                if (buffer.hasArray()){  //if byte buffer is used just get array
//                    byteArr = buffer.array();
//                }else{
//                    byteArr = directArr;  //if direct buffer is used, we get into direct arr
////                    Arrays.fill(byteArr, (byte)0);  //reset every value to "null" value
//                    buffer.get(byteArr, 0, buffer.remaining());
//                }
//                remaining = buffer.remaining();
//                runTask();
                BUFFER_POOL.returnBuffer(buffer);
            }
        }
        LOGGER.info(mainMarker,"Task Scheduler Thread has terminated...");
    }
```

However, when I run jvisualvm, I can see that whenever I "schedule" a task and poll the queue, it is allocating bytes. I have tried commenting and uncommenting the other parts of the code but only the polling and scheduling will affect the allocated bytes.

[image: jvisualvm]

I have checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63986434/how-to-iterate-through-arrayblockingqueue-without-memory-allocation-gc-delays) but I am not looking to iterate the whole array. I am looking to get one item at a time to process then remove it. What is the proper way to approach this?

edit: I have a separate thread that "produces" instances of ByteBuffer, InetSocketAddress and Marker and puts it inside the arrayblockingqueues. I also just checked the source code for poll() and dequeue() it doesn't seem that it does anything that should warrant the allocation of bytes. If I am creating the objects in the main thread, and adding it to queue, it shouldnt allocate bytes if this thread is only used for processing the queue values

The constructor looks like this:

```
private final BlockingQueue<ByteBuffer> TASK_BUFFER;
private final BlockingQueue<InetSocketAddress> TASK_ADDRESS;
private final BlockingQueue<Marker> TASK_MARKER;
private final BufferPool BUFFER_POOL;
private final ExcerptAppender APPENDER;

public TaskScheduler(BufferPool bufferPool, ChronicleQueue chronicleQueue){
    TASK_BUFFER = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(bufferPool.getCapacity());
    TASK_ADDRESS = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(bufferPool.getCapacity());
    TASK_MARKER = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(bufferPool.getCapacity());
    BUFFER_POOL = bufferPool;
    APPENDER = chronicleQueue.acquireAppender();
}
```

and this puts the produced values inside the queue:

```
    public void scheduleTask(final ByteBuffer buffer, final InetSocketAddress remoteAdd, final Marker marker) throws InterruptedException {
        TASK_BUFFER.put(buffer);
        TASK_ADDRESS.put(remoteAdd);
        TASK_MARKER.put(marker);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever an attempt to acquire a `ReentrantLock` is made, there’s potentiall a memory allocation. When there’s no contention or the lock is released during the spinning phase, the `lock()` method will return without allocations. But when the thread is added to the queue of waiting threads, a node object is allocated for that.

This applies to all classes using a `ReentrantLock` under the hood, like `ArrayBlockingQueue`, but also to all concurrency classes using `AbstractQueued[Long]Synchronizer` behind the scenes in general.

So your code looks like an attempted premature optimization that backfired. To avoid creating a simple object holding the `ByteBuffer`, `InetSocketAddress`, and `Marker` belonging to a task, you have three blocking queues requiring not only three `poll` calls but also to protect them with three `isEmpty()` checks, so you end up with up to six allocations in the worst case, instead of the one you had with a single `poll()` and `null` check when you used a single queue of objects holding all three values.

But the entire loop is literally a polling loop, repeatedly calling `poll()` without ever giving up the CPU. It’s creating the very overhead it (apparently) was supposed to avoid. Just calling `take()`, to only return when there is a new element would avoid this. This would queue the thread if there is no new element, but as said, a thread gets queued anyway when there’s contention at the lock and repeatedly calling `poll()` in a tight loop is a recipe to get contention sooner or later. On the other hand, `take()` will work exactly the same as `poll()` when there is a new element.

Comment: I see! But wouldnt the awaiting from `take()` cause context switch? I realised from your answer that using 3 blocking queues is kinda inefficient when I could just have one blocking queue of container objects that contains the items needed for a task, while reusing the container objects. I cant believe I didnt see that.

Comment: Would that mean that switching all instances of `poll()` to `take()` is the best way to proceed?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean by the term “context switch”. There is no technical difference between waiting for a condition, like “not empty”, or waiting for just getting the lock. Using `poll()` is only useful if your thread has something else to do while there’s nothing available. If all it does, is calling `poll()` again, just use `take()`.

Comment: if i m not mistaken when the execution of threads is paused, doesnt the state of the thread need to be stored so that it can resume execution again later? I remember reading that the storing of this state is expensive, especially if the context switch is done many times

Comment: There are different meanings for “storing and restoring the state of a thread”. One of them is happening all the time in multitasking operating system. The other, enqueuing a thread to wait for something, is exactly what has been described here. You’re already encountering it because the thread tries to acquire a contended lock. That’s why you’re seeing memory allocations. Yes, that’s expensive. Using `take()` doesn’t change that, except when the queue is empty, as then, it’ll avoid the repeated `poll()` calls which raises the chances that the `put(…)` calls are uncontended, hence, cheap.